# Swift: How to Use Segue when UICollectionViewCell(inside a UITableViewCell) is selected

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I want to use segue to show a detail page of the selected UICollectionViewCell, however this cell is inside a UITableViewCell. the problem is that I can't use "performSegueWithIdentifier" in the TableViewCell( the one contains the CollectionView), I understand that this function can only be used in UIViewController, but my data(from JSON) is got in the TableViewCell. I don't know how to access these from ViewController, or maybe I can use other way to select the CollectionViewCell in the TableViewCell. here is my code:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var posts1: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var posts2: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var categories: [Category] = [Category]()
var selectedPost1: Posts?
```

I have 2 arrays( post1, and posts2), I want the segue to show detail of all items both in posts1 and posts2 array.

I tried to add function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedPost1 = self.posts1[indexPath.row]


}
```

but inside I can't call "performSegueWithIdentifier". any suggestions about solving this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepareForSegue on the viewController and you can and check the identifier that you need, and then instantiate the correct view controller you want to move to. You can check this [example](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/)

Comment: I know how to use it when it is in a UITableViewController or UIViewController, but my cell is inside another cell, how can I call this function inside a cell?

Comment: You must have a main UITableViewController where your cell is correct ? And you created a segue from the cell to a detail view ? What I'm suggesting is you go to your UITableViewController you override prepareForSegue (not performSegueIdentifier). Like this for instance 
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}

Comment: yes, I already done this. But I have trouble in passing the data. I downloaded all the data from the internet and store them in an array, and the array is in the UICollectionView class(which is inside the TableView). How can I pass them in the main UITableViewController? it's like all my data is stored inside "posts1", how can I pass them to the main UITableView? thanks. sorry I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extension in your uitableviewcell

```
extension UITableViewCell {
var parentViewController: UITableViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UITableViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

then in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if let tableController = parentViewController as? NameOfYourTableViewController {
        tableController.performSegueWithIdentifier(SegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
    }
}
```